# How to get max of a column in informatica?

Tags: informatica

I am new to Informatica world

My source is like this

```
emp_id|emp_name|emp_sal
1     |  A     |   2500
2     |  C     |   2800
3     |  M     |   2100
```

I would like target to be like this..

```
emp_id|emp_name|emp_sal|maximum_salary
1     |    A   |  2500 |  2800
2     |    C   |  2800 |  2800
3     |    M   |  2100 |  2800
```

please help guys:)
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You didn't you show us what you've done so far, event if it doesn't work. We are volunteers. We'll help you repair you code, but no one will write _whole_ program for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Aggregator transformation. Create an output port in the Aggregator transformation with the expression MAX(emp_sal). Do not select any group by port.

Now join the output of Aggregator and your original source data using a Joiner transformation.

Also you have to use a sorter (key: emp_id) before the Aggregator and select the sorted input option in both the Aggregator and Joiner

```
SQ --> Sorter --> Aggregator -- Joiner --> Target
         |_________________________^
```

Comment: if im not using group by its coming as                                       3 | M | 2100 | 2800(only last row)..                                                          if im not using group by its coming as                                                           1     |    A   |  2500 |  2500
2     |    C   |  2800 |  2800
3     |    M   |  2100 | 2100

Comment: That is why you need the joiner! You cannot achieve this only by using Aggregator.

Answer (score 1):

According to the performance point of view, we need to use minimum number of transformations and try to reduce the blocking transformations like Joiner, Aggregator.

Here we can achieve this in two transformations.

```
 SQ --> Sorter --> Expression --> Output
```

In Sorter, Sort key is `emp_sal` as `descending`

Expression for `Max Salary` in Expression Transformation

```
Variable_Input1 - Variable_Input2
Input - emp_sal
Variable_Input2 - (IIF(Input > Variable_Input1, Input, Variable_Input1))
Output - Variable_Input2
```

Note: Datatype for Variable_Input1 & Variable_Input2 is Integer

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below steps.

SQ --> Sorter --> Expression -->Tgt

In Sorter t/r, Sort key is emp_sal as descending

Expression for Max Salary in Expression Transformation

v_PORT1(Integer) - v_PORT2
v_PORT2(Integer) -IIF(emp_sal > v_PORT1, emp_sal, v_PORT1)
o_PORT - v_PORT2

out put is coming like this.

emp_id|emp_name|emp_sal|maximum_salary
1     |    A   |  2500 |  2800
2     |    C   |  2800 |  2800
3     |    M   |  2100 |  2800

It's working for me.

Please check it and let me know.