# How to load the first half records in one file and other half in other file in informatica?

Tags: informatica

I have tried expression transformation so far along with aggregate transformation to get the maximum value of the sequence number.Source is flat file

Comment: What do you do when the count is odd?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are designing would require reading the source twice in the mapping, one to get the total number of records (max sequence as you called it) and then another one to read the detail records and pass them to target1 or target2.

You can simplify it by passing the number of records as a mapping parameter.

Either way, to decide when to route to a target - you can count the number of records read by keeping a running total in a variable port, incrementing every time a row passes thru the expression and checking against the (record count)/2.

Comment: See this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035173/how-to-get-max-of-a-column-in-informatica

Comment: Sorry guys i was sleeping that time.Now i'll tell you my requirement clear.i'm not supposed to use sequence generator transformation so instead of that i generated sequence using expression transformation.After that i gave it to aggregator to get the maximum value among the sequence.So that i can divide it by 2.But since i used aggregator transformation i selected group by ports.So it's not displaying the exact result that i expected

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really care about *first half and second half* and all you need is two output files equal in size, you can:

1. number the rows (with a rank transformation or a variable port),
2. then route even and odd rows to two different targets.

Comment: I've done it guys.I used a aggregator to get the count of the sequence numbers and i passed it to joiner(one from expression transformation and other from aggregator).For the join condition i created dummy port with a string value so that i can connect it both to joiner and aggregator..I gave the condition like masters dummy port = detail dummy port.After that i used router to check whether the sequence is less than the count value divided by 2.Now i got my result.Thanks guys for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

prior to writing to the target you keep counts in an expression. then connect this expression to a router.
 The router should have 2 groups

group1 count1 <= n/2 then route it to Target1 
group2 count1 > n/2 then route it to Target2

Or

MOD(nextval/2) will send alternative records to alternative targets. 
I guess it won't send first half to 1st target and 2nd half to 2nd target.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, write a Unix (assuming your platform is Unix) shell script to do a *head* of the first file with half the file size in lines (use *wc* of the file with the right param as the param to *head* after dividing it by 2) and direct the output to a 3rd file.  Then do a *tail* on the second file also using *wc* as just described and >> the output to the 3rd file you created.  These would be pre-session commands.  You'd use that 3rd file as the source file for your session.  It'd look *something* like this (untested, but it gets the general idea across):

```
halfsize=`wc -l filename`
halfsize=$((halfsize/2))
head -n $halfsize filename > thirdfile
halfsize=`wc -l filename2`
halfsize=$((halfsize/2))
tail -n $halfsize filename2 >> thirdfile
```