# how to dump first half of the records into one target and second half into another target?

Tags: informatica

Suppose I have 100 records in my source how to dump first 50 into one target and remaining 50 into another target ?
EX:
my source is not a flat file
    source :
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    target1:
    1
    2
    3
    target2:
    4
    5
    6
we need to assign the serial numbers using expression and then we need to find the last serial number in order to use as condition in router. How to find the highest serial number in expression transformation.

Comment: Which RDBMS? Oracle,MYSQL SQLSERVER ?

Comment: Oracle. I need to use transformations. not querry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load the first half records in one file and other half in other file in informatica?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32249364/how-to-load-the-first-half-records-in-one-file-and-other-half-in-other-file-in-i)

Comment: That question doesn't solves my question. we can't find the max of a column in expression because it works row wise. And if we use the source twice i.e one for serial number and another for finding max of the serial number(aggregator) then we can't connect the ports to router transformation

Comment: The thread linked above by Marek indeed solves it. It even talks about two approaches: either splitting to evens and odds (if you don't care about the FIRST and SECOND half) or doing a count and using it on router.
This is a duplicate, I'd say.